# How to format the date in KornShell script to DD-MON-YYYY?

Tags: shell, date, unix, ksh

How do I format a date in a KornShell (ksh) script to DD-MON-YYYY?

I have tried the following:

```
date '+%d-%h-%Y'
```

It returns **04-Nov-2009** I need for the Nov to be NOV (all caps).  Can this be done with the date utility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what finally worked on unix(solaris).

```
date '+%d-%h-%Y' | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]
```

returned: **04-NOV-2009**

Answer (score 5):

The <kbd>^</kbd> character forces uppercase in the GNU coreutils `date` (at least, it does in version  6.9.92.4 of coreutils):

```
$ date '+%d-%^h-%Y'
04-NOV-2009
```

Unfortunately, <kbd>^</kbd> is not [POSIX standard](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/date.html) for `date`, so you'll probably have to resort to a second command such as the [`tr` suggested by @martin clayton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677257/how-to-format-the-date-in-korn-shell-script-to-dd-mon-yyyy/1677283#1677283), if you aren't on a GNU system.

Comment: @Mark Rushakoff - This doesn't work on both uxix or linux.  I get the following when I execute: 04-^Nov-2009.

Comment: Suggested "above"?  Please reference a specific answer.  Orders change with voting,

Answer (score 2):

You could uppercase it yourself if caret uppercase is not supported in your environment:

```
date '+%d-%h-%Y' | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
```

Comment: @martin clayton - This syntax worked on linux but not unix and my script is running on a unix box.  However, your code snippet pointed me the right direction.  Thx!